# Milliseconds in Exported Files

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am generating export from _sent data view using SQL, but my client wants to see the date fields should have milliseconds as well, currently it's showing me in format of "2020-04-21 20:38:00" Is their a way I can pull milliseconds for all date fields in _send data view?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If that's what they want... Cast your datetime field to nvarchar using a style, like this, and then extract out the string value:

```
SELECT TOP 10
    CONVERT(nvarchar(23),EventDate,21) AS EventDateString
FROM ENT._Sent

-- Returns ODBC Canonical date string - "2019-11-05 02:35:34.280"
```

You can refer to [Microsoft's SQL Server documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for other styles available.

Probably most portable would be converting to using ISO-8601 formatting (MSSQL style 127) where the client can understand the timezone the data pertains to:

```
SELECT TOP 10
    CONVERT(nvarchar(24),EventDate
        AT TIME ZONE 'Central Standard Time'
        AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
    ,127) AS EventDateString
FROM ENT._Sent

-- Returns ISO-8601 date string in UTC - "2019-11-05T08:35:34.280Z"
```